# ArrayList in the end is null

Tags: java, arraylist

I am collecting from a form some values, which I add them to an ArrayList and then I create an object.

```
     ArrayList<Integer> machines = new ArrayList<>();
     ArrayList<WorkPosition> workPositions = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int i=1; i<=positions; i++){
            fname1 = "position"+i+"-1";
            fname2 = "position"+i+"-2";
            fname3 = "position"+i+"-3"

            m1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter(fname1));
            m2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter(fname2));
            m3 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter(fname3));

            if(m1!=0)
                machines.add(m1);
            if(m2!=0)
                machines.add(m2);
            if(m3!=0)
                machines.add(m3);

            WorkPosition workPosition = new WorkPosition(0, i, machines, false, date); //Here I create the Object 
            workPositions.add(workPosition);

            machines.clear();

        }
```

After I create the object (type WorkPosition) and add it to my list, I delete the ArrayList machines, so the next object which will be created in the 2nd loop hasn't the elements of the previous object. However when I print the arraylist machines at the end of the loop to see what it has with

```
   for(WorkPosition i:workPositions){
         System.out.println("WorkPosition " +i.getWorkPosition() + " :" + " Machines{ "+ i.getMachines() +" }");
   }
```

In the Class Machines, I have this getter:

```
public class WorkPosition {

    private int workPosition;
    ArrayList<Integer> machines = new ArrayList<>();

    //more code...


    public ArrayList<Integer> getMachines() {
        return machines;
    }
```

I get this print:

```
WorkPosition 1 : Machines{ [] }
WorkPosition 2 : Machines{ [] }
```

Any thoughts why is this happening? If i delete the `machines.clear();` I get this output:

```
WorkPosition 1 : Machines{ [1, 15] }
WorkPosition 2 : Machines{ [1, 15] }
```

However the desire output would be:

```
WorkPosition 1 : Machines{ [1] }
WorkPosition 2 : Machines{ [15] }
```

**UPDATE:**
I put the `ArrayList<Integer> machines = new ArrayList<>();` inside the loop and removed the `machines.clear()` and it worked..

Comment: what is the value of `positions` in `for (int i=1; i<=positions; i++)` ?? is it 2??

Comment: yes in this case is two.

Comment: this part of the code doesn't affect the question. I just don't want to add zeros "0" to the list.

Comment: No, in the 1st loop i get the `[1]` and in the 2nd loop I get the `[15]`. However I found a way.. I put the ArrayList<Integer> machines = new ArrayList<>(); inside the loop and removed the machines.clear() and it worked

Comment: well done..!! I learnt something too!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the WorkPosition, you give it a reference to machines.  Therefore, when you call `machines.clear()`, you clear the machines ArrayList in the WorkPosition, too.

Instead, you should set machines to a new ArrayList:

```
machines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This will clear machines while leaving the ArrayList in WorkPosition intact.

Comment: I have defined theses ArrayLists already (I updated the question).

Comment: Well your answer got me in thoughts and i put the `ArrayList<Integer> machines = new ArrayList<>();` inside the loop and removed the `machines.clear()` and it worked!

Comment: `machines` is not actually an ArrayList, like `int i` is an int, but is just a pointer to an ArrayList.  When you pass `machines` to the WorkPosition constructor, you are giving it a reference, not the object.  Thus, when you clear `machines`, you clear the ArrayList `machines` points to.  Since WorkPosition points to the same ArrayList, it no longer has any values.  When you call `machines = new ArrayList<Integer>()`, you change machines so it points to a new ArrayList, and not the old one.  The old one remains intact.